# Display remaining and needed disk space in a WPF App in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that allows a bunch of checkboxes to be selected which govern which applications you are going to install. I am trying to make it so that the user can see how much space is empty when they select a folder and how much will be required. Kind of like the Visual Studio Installer where, as you select more components, the disk space is updated.

I would like to have that information displayed on a label. I have a FolderBrowserDialog which allows you to select the path. Say for instance- a label for empty space (lblEmptySpace) and one for required space which is updated as more applications are selected (lblRequiredSpace).

Answer (score 1):

You can check official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace?view=net-6.0)

Example:

```
private static long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
{
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
        {
            return drive.TotalFreeSpace;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: one liner:  `return DriveInfo.GetDrives().FirstOrDefault(d =>d.IsReady && d.Name.Equals(dirveName))?.TotalFreeSpace ?? -1`